# OOP visibility in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have recently started OOP in PHP and I am on visibility concept (public, protected, private). Here I'm confused about protected visibility. Protected members can only be accessible within the declaring clas or a subclass or child class. I have this example on PHP's site:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}


class MyClass2 extends MyClass
{
    // We can redeclare the public and protected method, but not private
    protected $protected = 'Protected2';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj2 = new MyClass2();
echo $obj2->public; // Works
echo $obj2->protected; // Fatal Error
echo $obj2->private; // Undefined
$obj2->printHello(); // Shows Public, Protected2, Undefined
```

In this code in the third last line (`echo $obj2->protected; // Fatal Error`) it gives fatal error. But isn't protected variable inherited into child class which is MyClass2 in this case? So why this fatal error? Can someone please enlighten me about this?

Comment: You are trying to access a `protected` member outside of the scope of both classes.

Comment: `echo $obj2->protected; // Fatal Error` This line is outside both the classes. How is it supposed to work then? It would only work with public that way

Comment: And you have yourself demonstrated in the `printHello` method that your child can access the protected property of parent fine.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky he just copy and pasted it directly from the PHP Manual

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks. Protected variable becomes member of inheriting class and we cannot echo it directly in it but with the help of a function which it is doing in printHello() function in MyClass2 class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> Protected members can only be accessible **within** the declaring class or
>   a subclass or child class.

You must pay attention to the **within**.

You're getting the fatal error because you're accessing `$protected` from outside both `MyClass2` and `MyClass`.

**Within** means that you can access it from `MyClass2` like you're doing on `MyClass2::printHello()` and/or `MyClass::printHello()` methods.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it but I have one related confusion. Can we echo variables within the declaring class or we have to create an object outside the class and then access the class variable through object and echo it? It might sound stupid but I'm really new to OOP stuff. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: One of the TOP concepts about OOP is [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29): class' properties belongs to the object where they were declared, so, most of the time you need to first create a new object and than access its properties/methods. I wrote "most of the time" because you have [static properties/methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) which do not require an object instance to be accessed (ie `MyClass::$static_property`)

Comment: I would suggest you to read about getters/setters, maybe it will enlighten you.

Comment: It helped clear my doubts and will make my OOP journey better. Thanks a ton for your help Paulo.